# How can I rename class-names via Xml attributes?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Suppose I have an XML-serializable class called **Song**:

```
[Serializable]
class Song
{
    public string Artist;
    public string SongTitle;
}
```

In order to save space (and also *semi-obfuscate* the XML file), I decide to rename the xml elements:

```
[XmlRoot("g")]
class Song
{
    [XmlElement("a")]
    public string Artist;
    [XmlElement("s")]
    public string SongTitle;
}
```

This will produce XML output like this:

```
<Song>
  <a>Britney Spears</a>
  <s>I Did It Again</s>
</Song>
```

I want to rename/remap the name of the class/object as well. Say, in the above example, I wish to rename the class **Song** to **g**. So that the resultant xml should look like this:

```
<g>
  <a>Britney Spears</a>
  <s>I Did It Again</s>
</g>
```

Is it possible to rename class-names **via xml-attributes**?

I don't wish to create/traverse the DOM manually, so I was wondering if it could be achieved via a decorator.

I'm actually serializing a list of Song objects in the XML.

Here's the serialization code:

```
    public static bool SaveSongs(List<Song> songs)
    {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Song>));
            using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("filename"))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(textWriter, songs);
            }
    }
```

And here's the XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfSong>
<Song>
  <a>Britney Spears</a>
  <s>Oops! I Did It Again</s>
</Song>
<Song>
  <a>Rihanna</a>
  <s>A Girl Like Me</s>
</Song>
</ArrayOfSong>
```

Apparently, the **XmlRoot()** attribute doesn't rename the object in a list context.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think there is an error in the XML. "I did it again" is not the correct title of the song. The correct title is; "Oops!...I Did It Again". (Just to prevent future frustrations with validators)

Comment: FYI, `[Serializable]` doesn't matter to XML Serialization.

Comment: See my updated response based on your clarification.

Comment: It's been a few years, so it might be item to update the correct answer :) *The answer currently marked as correct is actually incorrect for the question asked (and does not result in the desired output).* `XmlTypeAttribute` and its `TypeName` property is the correct way to do it (see below).

Comment: @Ariel Popovsky: If you check the edits, even the very first version of the question would not have worked with `XmlRoot`. The OP has not been on here for 2 years, so it will continue to mislead coders everywhere :)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Checkout the XmlRoot attribute.

Documentation can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute(v=VS.90).aspx

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "www.contoso.com", 
     ElementName = "MyGroupName", 
     DataType = "string", 
     IsNullable=true)]
public class Group
```

UPDATE:
Just tried and it works perfectly on VS 2008.
This code:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "sgr")]
public class SongGroup
{
    public SongGroup()
    {
       this.Songs = new List<Song>();
    }



[XmlElement(ElementName = "sgs")]
    public List<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "g")]
public class Song
{
    [XmlElement("a")]
    public string Artist { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("s")]
    public string SongTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sgr xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www
.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <sgs>
    <a>A1</a>
    <s>S1</s>
  </sgs>
  <sgs>
    <a>A2</a>
    <s>S2</s>
  </sgs>
</sgr>
```

Comment: @Arial: Had the same problem but found the XmlRoot attribute only works on my root node (as I guess it should based on the docs). Not sure how you got the above code to work properly. Got it to work with [XmlType(TypeName = "newName")] on my classes instead.

Comment: The Output is not correct you loose a <g>...</g> but this not solve the problem. The solution is the post of "HiTech Magic" [XmlType(TypeName="g")]

Comment: @Ariel Popovsky, what if i want Song to be an element named "g" and Artist and SongTitle to be attributes on that element. IE, `<sgr><sgs><g a="A1" s="S1" /><g a="A2" s="S2"><sgs><sgr>`

Comment: @theB3RV use [XmlAttribute("a")] and [XmlAttribute("s")] instead of XmlElement and you'll get attributes instead of elements. To rename the Song from sgs to g, just change the ElementName in the Songs list XmlElement Attribute.

Comment: @ArielPopovsky Notice I want <sgs> AND <g> elements. I cant get the parent element <sgs></sgs> with multiple <g> elements inside. I can see how to do it by changing the class name song to g but that defeats the purpose. or i could create a model that contains only the property of list of songs and name it g but that breaks the rest of my code.

Comment: `XmlArrayItem("g")` is what i was looking for

Answer (score 135):

### Solution: Use [XmlType(TypeName="g")]

**XmlRoot only works with XML *root* nodes** as per the documentation (and what you would expect, given its name includes *root*)!

I was unable to get any of the other answers to work so kept digging...

Instead I found that the *XmlTypeAttribute* (i.e. `[XmlType]`) and its *TypeName* property do a similar job for *non-root* classes/objects.

e.g.

```
[XmlType(TypeName="g")]
class Song
{
    public string Artist;
    public string SongTitle;
}
```

Assuming you apply it to the other classes e.g.:

```
[XmlType(TypeName="a")]
class Artist
{
    .....
}

[XmlType(TypeName="s")]
class SongTitle
{
    .....
}
```

This will output the following *exactly as required in the question*:

```
<g>
  <a>Britney Spears</a>
  <s>I Did It Again</s>
</g>
```

I have used this in several production projects and found no problems with it.

Comment: it still outputs <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>

Comment: @piedpiper: That is down to the output encoding, not the `XmlType` described here. Please ask a new question if you have one :)

Comment: This answer works a lot better than the chosen answer.

Comment: @DotNetProgrammer: Unfortunately the OP has not been online for many years so it remains stuck on an incorrect answer :)

Comment: This solution does not work for me for the root node. The accepted answer works.

Comment: @GoneCoding the accepted answer is correct for the original question, which was later edited. It won't let me remove my downvote. Sorry.

Comment: How does this work? The "Artist" and "SongTitle" in the first example are *property names*, not types, defined as *string*s.  What role does XmlType play on class Artist, if its not used? This example does not make much sense to me...

Comment: @ThatMarc "Assuming you apply it to the other classes": that was just an example, to be used if they had nested classes rather than have string properties. Just trying to cover additional options here. Given the asker is long gone (and will never correct his accepted answer), you might was to ask a new question.

Comment: @GoneCoding sorry for being late as well, only seen this now. And I apologize, I was misguided by that very statement as if it was "Assuming you apply it to the other classes TOO", so my bad on that side! On another note, the *correct* way to do non-root elements would be using "XmlElement" instead, that's what we're using for all custom serializers and kinda makes sense especially when using it along with XmlAttribute, XmlRoot and XmlText -> You kinda know what's what right away, never really tried the XmlType for all of them though.

Comment: On a side note it's worth mentioning that given the OP wanted to minify the end result XML, (although I'd argue its more readable and better in any case), I'd suggest using combination of XmlElement and XmlAttribute.
Element is an xml node, whereas attribute is a property of the element (attributeX=valueY), so you end up with an example for a song, such as:
`<song a="Britney Spears" t="I Did It Again" />`, with a for artist and t for title respectively. One can also add `XmlElement("songs", typeof(SongTitle))` on top of the `SongTitle[] Songs` array, and whole array is serialized like that.

Answer (score 5):

If this is the root element of the document, you can use [[XmlRoot("g")]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx).

---

Here is my updated response based on your clarification.  The degree of control you are asking for is not possible without a wrapping class.  This example uses a `SongGroup` class to wrap the list so that you can give alternate names to the items within.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class SongGroup
{
    public SongGroup()
    {
        this.Songs = new List<Song>();
    }

    [XmlArrayItem("g", typeof(Song))]
    public List<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}

public class Song 
{ 
    public Song()
    {
    }

    [XmlElement("a")] 
    public string Artist { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("s")]
    public string SongTitle { get; set; }
} 

internal class Test
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SongGroup));

        SongGroup group = new SongGroup();
        group.Songs.Add(new Song() { Artist = "A1", SongTitle = "S1" });
        group.Songs.Add(new Song() { Artist = "A2", SongTitle = "S2" });

        using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, group);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This has the side effect of generating one more inner element representing the list itself.  On my system, the output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SongGroup xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Songs>
    <g>
      <a>A1</a>
      <s>S1</s>
    </g>
    <g>
      <a>A2</a>
      <s>S2</s>
    </g>
  </Songs>
</SongGroup>
```

Comment: I realise this is a very old question/answer, but the specific output they wanted *is* available with `XmlType(TypeName="g")]`. You do not need a wrapping class and can just attribute the classes themselves. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use XmlElementAttribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName="g")]
class Song
{
    public string Artist;
    public string SongTitle;
}
```

should work.

Comment: Song is not the Root element, so this will not work. XmlRoot only applies at the root node. Sorry.

Answer (score -2):

```
[XmlRoot("g")]
class Song
{
}
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Song is not the Root element, so this will not work. XmlRoot only applies at the root node. Sorry.