# How can I rename XML root ArrayOfElement in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer, typeof

I have serializable class:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "News"), XmlType("News")] // I tried many attributes...
public class News
{
    [XmlElement("Article")]
    public List<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}
```

And method for serialization:

```
public static void SerializeToXML(Object obj)
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
    ...
}
```

**I would like to have the first XML element `<News>` but it is `<ArrayOfArticle>`.**

Note, I've found many [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653411/how-can-i-rename-class-names-via-xml-attributes)s but it seems I have another problem...

If I use `...XmlSerializer(typeof(News));` instead of `...obj.GetType()` everything is okay. But there is something wrong with `obj.GetType()`. It causes that `(ser.mapping).ElementName` is `"ArrayOfArticle"`. What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I've been able to find to do this in the past is to create a simple wrapper object which is decorated with the XmlRoot attribute and use it in place of your List.

```
[XmlRoot("Articles")]
public class Articles : List<Article> { }
```

There could be a more standard way to achieve it but I know this works every time.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I had that wrapper implemented but I passed bad object to my method. Your Answer pointed me to this. Problem was between chair and my keyboard... Thank you and sorry for your time.